# Drag and Drop File into Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, drag-and-drop, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form in Microsoft Access which lets users upload attachments to each record. I'd like to make it a little user friendly by letting users drag and drop files into the attachment field. What is the best way of doing this/how do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to drag and drop "attached" files for use with MS Access. (Currently using Office 365 Version 1811)

Access currently allows drag and drop to a hyperlink field.
Using this capability this example allows drag and drop to store an attachment file to a storage location while keeping a link to the original and new locations.

The event runs when a file is dropped into the HyperlinkIn box on the form or when the hyperlink is changed the normal way.

It is better to store the file in a storage location with a link than to store it within the .accdb file due to the 2GB limitation. You might call this a database + file server architecture. By using the record number and optionally the database and table name and attachment number you can ensure unique file names.

Make a Table and Form with 3 fields.
ID (AutoNumber)
HyperlInkIN  (hyperlink)
HyperLinkOUT (hyperlink)

Insert this VBA code for AfterUpdate event for the HyperlinkIn form control.

```
Private Sub HyperlinkIN_AfterUpdate()
    Dim InPath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim OutFolder As String
    Dim OutPath As String
    Dim RecordNo As String
    Dim FileExt As String

    OutFolder = "\\networkdrive\vol1\attachments\"  'specify the output folder  
    
    InPath = Me!HyperlinkIN.Hyperlink.Address
    RecordNo = Me!ID

    ' BrianDP Added next 3 lines of Code to fix Path if Local to C Drive 
    If Left(InPath, 6) = "..\..\" Then  
       InPath = "c:\" & Right(InPath, Len(InPath) - 6)  
    End If  

    If Len(InPath) > 0 Then
        FileName = Right(InPath, Len(InPath) - InStrRev(InPath, "\"))  'get the file name
        FileExt = Right(FileName, Len(FileName) - InStrRev(FileName, ".") + 1) ' get the file extension with dot

    'build the new path with output folder path and record number and date and extension
            OutPath = OutFolder & "Record " & RecordNo & " Attachment " & Format(Now(), "ddmmmyy") & FileExt 
        
        FileCopy InPath, OutPath
    
        Me!HyperlinkOUT = "#" & OutPath & "#"  
    
        MsgBox "Copied file to archives   " & vbCrLf & InPath & vbCrLf & OutPath
    End If
End Sub
```

I am somewhat inexperienced with VBA so there may be better ways to ensure and verify a successful file copy but this example works for me and is easy for me to understand. I used the MsgBox to help debug with the actual file copy commented out.

Comment: I tried this, then tried dragging a file from Explorer to the form. I got the circle-slash symbol, meaning I could not drop it there. I suspect I'm missing something very basic about drag-and-drop.

Comment: There is a very strange behavior. At first it worked perfectly. The next day out of the blue it gives me "Run-time error '53': File not found" error. What's the catch here ?

Answer (score 1):

Drag and drop might be a bit more sophisticated, how about VBA code to manipulate what you wish to achieve? This article has a great reference to what you wish to do. http://www.access-freak.com/tutorials.html#Tutorial07

Answer (score 0):

Because this page comes as first when searching for "MS Access drag drop", I'm adding my part here. If you are after some cool UI, you can checkout my [Github](https://github.com/krishKM/VBA_TOOLS/blob/master/README.md#drag-and-drop-openfiledialog) for sample database using .NET wrapper dll. Which allows you to simply call a function and to open filedialog with **file-drag-and-drop** function. Result is returned as a JSONArray string.

code can be simple as

```
Dim FilePaths As String
    FilePaths = gDll.DLL.ShowDialogForFile("No multiple files allowed", False)
'Will return a JSONArray string.
'Multiple files can be opend by setting AllowMulti:=true
```

here what it looks like;

[image: In Action]