# drop file into unbound hyperlink box in Access form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I try to use a hyperlink box in a Microsoft Access form (current Office 365) as kind of a workaround for implementing a file drop field as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53889581/1349511). I only need the path of the dropped file for further processing by VBA code - I do not need to store the value into the database. Therefore I switched the hyperlink box to unbound. After that, dropping a file is not possible any more.

Is this by design: drag and drop into a hyperlink box is only enabled for *bound* hyperlink boxes?

Note: possibly duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36517896/1349511)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems dropping sth. to a black hole (unbound control) wasn't considered by designers ;)

But you can create temporary recordsets with`Adodb.Recordset`and bind it to a form. If control is bound to a field of that recordset, you can drop files (controls`Hyperlink`property needs to be true) , but nothing is stored outside memory (you can save the temporary recordset to a file or even reconnect to tables to save data).

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim rs As Object 'ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")  'New ADODB.Recordset

    With rs
        Const adLongVarChar As Long = 201
        .Fields.Append "Hyperlink", adLongVarChar, 2000 ' create field to bind to control
        Const adUseClient As Long = 3
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient 'needed to make rs editable, when bound to form
        Const adOpenDynamic As Long = 2
        Const adLockOptimistic As Long = 3
        .Open , , adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, 8

        .AddNew 'create one record to store link
        .Fields("Hyperlink").value = ""
        .Update
    End With
    Set Me.Recordset = rs
    Me("controlName").ControlSource = "Hyperlink" ' bind textbox to rs field
End Sub
```

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this approach. Although `Form_Load()` sets the form recordset and assigns my unbound control's cource to the field "Hyperlink" (as verified by `Debug.Print`) I still can not drop files into that control.

Comment: You tested with a new blank form, only contains a textbox named `controlName`? Maybe you disallowed edit or sth. similar..

Comment: Yes, I did: blank form, TextBox control called `txtHyperlink`, your `Form_Load` code with only changing second-to-last line's code to `Me("txtHyperlink").ControlSource = "Hyperlink"`. No file dropping possible. I'm on current Office 365. Did it work for you?

Comment: My code is tested on Access 2013 x86. Can you write to the textbox? If not check forms recordset properties (put breakpoint after `Set Me.Recordset = rs`and a watch on`Me.Recordset`, then check cursor and lock-type).

Comment: That's it - I didn't know there's a property to set separately. Your solution works, my workaround is obsolete. Thank you for the clarification; good you added this to your post: will prevent other ignorants from running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This workaround turned out to be obsolete as the solution first given by ComputerVersteher does the job, if it's used correctly - my fault.

You may want to re-use the following lines of my workaround to process the path generated by dropping a file:

```
Dim sPath As String
sPath = Me.txtLink.Hyperlink.Address
    ' NOTE: Hyperlink.Address returns '..\..\..' relative to database location
    '  =>   (a) add current project path
    '       (b) use FileSystemObject to get full qualified path
sPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\" & sPath
sPath = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(sPath).Path
```

**End of edit**

As the previous answer (at least for me) didn't solve the problem maybe this can only be adressed by a workaround. I've build a reusable solution as follows (sample database [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fEcPID3SPNIp1IML4epT2FTeuINIIK_B/view?usp=sharing)):

(1) Create a table called `tblDropZone` with only one field named `fldLink` of type `Link`.

(2) Create a form called `frmDropZone`, set `RecordSource` to `tblDropZone`; create a `TextBox` control on that form, name it `txtLink` and set it's `ControlSource` to `fldLink`.

(3) Create a form called `frmDropZoneTest`, put `frmDropZone` on it as subform `sfrmDropZone`; create an unbound `TextBox` control called `txtDropZonePath`.

(4) Add the following code to `frmDropZone`:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Const mcsParentControlName As String = "txtDropZonePath"
' note: change here if name of control in master form changed!


Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.Recordset.AddNew
End Sub


Private Sub txtLink_AfterUpdate()
    Dim sPath As String
    sPath = Me.txtLink.Hyperlink.Address
        ' NOTE: Hyperlink.Address returns '..\..\..' relative to database location
        '  =>   (a) add current project path
        '       (b) use FileSystemObject to get full qualified path
    sPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\" & sPath
    sPath = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(sPath).Path

    ' empty "drop zone"-control and cancel record edit
    Me.txtLink = Null
    Me.Undo

    ' if used as subform then
    '   (1) write value to parent form's control as defined in constant
    '   (2) call event handler in parent form 
    '       note: the AfterUpdate of the parent form's control does not fire 
    '             on control's value change by code
    If HasParent(Me) Then
        Me.Parent.Controls(mcsParentControlName).Value = sPath
            ' you may want to add some error handling on this
        Me.Parent.DropZoneWorkaround_Event 
            ' this has to be a public sub in parent form code
            ' you may want to add some error handling on this
    End If
End Sub


Private Function HasParent(F As Object) As Boolean
    'https://stackoverflow.com/a/57884609/1349511
    'Inspired from: https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=293282   @Sep 10th, 2019
    Dim bHasParent As Boolean
    On Error GoTo noParents

    bHasParent = Not (F.Parent Is Nothing)
    HasParent = True
    Exit Function

noParents:
   HasParent = False
End Function
```

(5) Add the following code to `frmDropZoneTest`:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

' unbound TextBox 'txtDropZonePath' will be filled by subform 'frmDropZone'
' NOTES:
'   define name of this TextBox as constant in subform code
'   public sub as event handler needed (called from subform)

Private Sub txtDropZonePath_AfterUpdate()
    Debug.Print "Path: " & txtDropZonePath
End Sub

Public Sub DropZoneWorkaround_Event()
    txtDropZonePath_AfterUpdate
End Sub
```

(6) Cosmetics:

- With `frmDropZone`

  - remove label for `txtLink`
  - set `txtLink` control's Width and Height as needed
  - move `txtLink` control to the upper left corner
  - set `.NavigationButtons = False`
  - set `.RecordSelectors = False`
- With `frmDropZoneTest`

  - adjust the subform control's `Width` and `Height` so that exactly the `txtLink` control of the subform fits in. For me, it needed to be about 0,01 cm more than the `txtLink` control on the subform.
  - optional set `txtDropZonePath.Visible = False`

You can copy and paste `sfrmDropZone` to other forms if you make sure they all have an unbound TextBox called `txtDropZonePath` and a `Public Sub DropZoneWorkaround_Event()` to be called from the subform's code `txtLink_AfterUpdate()` event, to handle the dropped file's path.